# Бесполезный конструктор копии C++

Tags: c++

Конструктор копии - механизм для предотвращения потери данных. Например, если передаваемый объект содержит указатели на дин. выделенную память. В моём случае это не работает.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myclass {
public:
    int *var;
    myclass(int i) { cout << "Obuchnuy konstructor.\n"; var = new int; *var = i; }
    myclass(const myclass &obj) { cout << "Konstructor kopii.\n"; var = new int; *var = *obj.var; }
    ~myclass() { cout << "Destructor.\n"; delete var; }
};

myclass f()
{
    myclass ob(5);
    cout << *ob.var << endl;
    return ob;
}

int main()
{
    myclass a(10);
    cout << *a.var << endl;
    a = f();
    cout << *a.var << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Выводится "мусор":

```
Obuchnuy konstructor.
10
Obuchnuy konstructor.
5
Konstructor kopii.
Destructor.
Destructor.
-17891602
Destructor.
```

Зачем вообще его использовать, если дин. память была очищается оператором **delete** так же, как была бы очищена без конструктора копии? Только без него "мусор" появится при вызове деструктора объекта **myclass::ob**, а с ним при вызове деструктора временного объекта.

Comment: В С++ *obj.var принято записывать как obj->var

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы забыли переопределить оператор присваивания. А он явно вызывается в вашем коде (`a = f();`).

В вашем случае используется оператор присваивания по умолчанию, который просто копирует все поля, включая и поле с указателем. Таким образом, у вам снова получаются два объекта с указателем на одни и те же данные, и когда один из них умирает, он «убивает» и чужие данные.

Судя по всему, вам повезло, и вы используете отладочную версию программы и дружественный компилятор, в котором уничтожаемые данные меняют значение. В обыкновенном случае данные могли бы внешне не измениться, и вы бы обнаружили ошибку гораздо позже.

Обратите внимание на правила «большой двойки», «большой тройки» (и в современных версиях языка большой пятёрки):

1. Если вам в классе нужен конструктор копирования или оператор присваивания, то нужны *оба*. (Скорее всего, вам они понадобятся, если у вас в классе есть поля-указатели.)
2. Если ваш класс не запрещает наследование, то в в список пункта 1 вам нужно добавить ещё и виртуальный деструктор: если вам нужен один из трёх, то нужны все три.

(Вот [подробный ответ про правило пятёрки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782927/276994) для новых версий языка с move semantics. Если вы не пользуетесь move semantics, достаточно правила тройки.)